# ng.probe overrides by angular-elements

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, angular-elements

I have `chrome extension` which injects angular-elements to the page. Extension is supposed to be run on the pages with the Angular application.

There are two different issues I've faced with:

- building angular-elements without `optimization:true` flag leads to broken element: element is not initialized at the page, e.g. only `<my-element></my-element>` is created without anything inside. Not really critical problem but in sake of interest I'd like to understand why.
- `ng.probe()` for main application is stopped to work because it's replaced from  `angular-elements` one. So that, after injecting `angular-element` at the page it's possible to `probe` only DOM elements from the `angular-element`.

Angular 7.2.0, document-register-element 1.13.2.

I've looked at angular source-code and I'd not found way to prevent replacing `ng.probe`, seems like the latest angular app replaces ng.probe from the own scope. Since I'm not an expert with angular internals it'd be great to find the way to not override `ng.probe` in `angular-elements`.